# Split string without removing delimiter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to parse a file to get individual SQL statements and run them from rails controller.

I have the following code:

```
@sql_file = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/evidence_interface_import.sql"   
@sql_stmts_array = File.read(@sql_file).split(";")  

@sql_stmts_array.each_with_index do |sql_stmt,s_index|
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_stmt)
end
```

The split removes the ";" from the end of the SQLs. Is there a way not to remove the ";" and still split using ";".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
@sql_stmts_array = File.read(@sql_file).lines(separator=';')
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong for `lines(separator=';')` - that will work but it's poorly written. It should be `lines(';')` instead. But, use `File.readlines(@sql_file, ';')` instead because it's shorter and accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 16):

Yup, [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) it:

```
'a; b; c;'.scan(/[^;]*;/)
#=> ["a;", " b;", " c;"]
```

You could get rid of the excess whitespace by tacking on `map(&:strip)` after, but it's probably not needed here.

Note that this is very rudimentary, and something like a string literal in the SQL with a semicolon in it will break this. (E.g. `select * from stuff where name = ";";`.)

Comment: A similar option would be: `'a; b; c;'.scan(/.*?;/)`

Answer (score 9):

When using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` you don't need to include the semicolon in the first place.

Also, another way to split without removing the delimiter is to use groups as shown in the following example:

```
"a;b;c".split(/;/)   # => ["a", "b", "c"]

"a;b;c".split(/(;)/) # => ["a", ";", "b", ";", "c"]
```

Comment: for many cases involving tokenization and string manipulation - this is a great solution.

Comment: I would mark this as the accepted answer. `scan` seems to need the delimiter after each item, not just between them.

Answer (score 6):

Use a regex with a lookbehind

```
split(/(?<=;)/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `scan` with an appropriate regex, which should give you results similar to `split`, but if you want to stick to a way without regex, you can just append a semi-colon to each cell in the array:

```
@sql_stmts_array = File.read(@sql_file).split(";").each do |s|
  s << ";"
end
```

Comment: This has a side-effect of putting a semicolon after the last entry.

Comment: Isn't that what is wanted? Shouldn't there be a `;` after each entry?