# Ruby: how to split a string on a regex while keeping the delimiters?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

This has [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089562/how-do-i-split-a-string-keeping-the-delimiters-in-ruby) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363296/ruby-how-to-split-string-while-keeping-delimiter-and-delimiter-has-length-1) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957858/split-string-into-a-list-but-keeping-the-split-pattern) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539689/split-string-without-removing-delimiter) around here, but never got a generic answer, so here we go:

Say you have a string, any string, but let's go with `"oruh43451rohcs56oweuex59869rsr"`, and you want to split it with a regular expression. Any regular expression, but let's go with a sequence of digits: `/\d+/`. Then you'd use `split`:

```
"oruh43451rohcs56oweuex59869rsr".split(/\d+/)
# => ["oruh", "rohcs", "oweuex", "rsr"]
```

That's lovely and all, but I want the digits. So for that we have `scan`:

```
"oruh43451rohcs56oweuex59869rsr".scan(/\d+/)
# => ["43451", "56", "59869"]
```

But I want it all! Is there, say, a `split_and_scan`? Nope.

How about I `split` and `scan` then `zip` them? Let me stop you right there.

Ok, so how?

Comment: What's your expected output? Could you explain what you mean by general solution?

Comment: a general solution is one that works for any valid given input; in this case, any string and any regexp.

Comment: @Chris Heald suggest the capturing group solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `split`'s pattern contains a capture group, the group will be included in the resulting array.

```
str = "oruh43451rohcs56oweuex59869rsr"
str.split(/(\d+)/)
# => ["oruh", "43451", "rohcs", "56", "oweuex", "59869", "rsr"]
```

If you want it zipped,

```
str.split(/(\d+)/).each_slice(2).to_a
# => [["oruh", "43451"], ["rohcs", "56"], ["oweuex", "59869"], ["rsr"]]
```

Comment: Nice. I actually knew this but totally forgot about it. I'm not sure the "zip" solution would work in every case.

Comment: @kch: I believe it should, as long as you include exactly one capture group in the delimiter. If the string *starts* with the delimiter, the first group is `["", "delim"]`. The last one is a bit anomalous, but also makes sense - the delimiter will be read as `nil`, which is okay because it really does not exist.

Comment: I think you're right. Anyhow, you might wanna go to the previous questions I linked and post this answer (I don't recall seeing it in them, but maybe it was buried down.)). It's simpler than my custom implementation, probably faster, and more powerful with multiple captures.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I mean, given that the pattern for delimiters is `\d+`, you needed to have both `\d+` and `\D+` - the delimiter and the stuff between the delimiters was easy to define. If the delimiter is more complex such as the example OP gave (`/\w\d+\w/`), it is non-trivial to come up with a pattern for the other side of the alternation (i.e. one that would match `["oru", "ohc", "weue", "sr"]` in the example string), making the `str.scan(/#{delim}|#{notdelim}/)` method impossible to generalise; the `split` method makes it trivial (`str.split(/(\w\d+\w)/)`).

Comment: @Amadan thanks for your explanation. Now i understood but i think you could still use scan function `string.scan(/\w\d+\w|(?:(?!\w\d+\w).)+/)` ie, `string.scan(/delim|(?:(?!delim).)+/)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Fair enough, yeah, that looks general enough. There is another issue - if you have neighbouring delimiters, (i.e. null-length fields), it will be hard in the `scan` solution to differentiate which is which. `000delimdelim000` -> `["000", "delim", "delim", "000"]` with `scan`, `["000", "delim", "", "delim", "000"] with `split`. Still, awesome job on coming up with a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you asked… well, there's [`String#shatter`](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/string/shatter.rb) from [Facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets). I don't love it because it's implemented using trickery (look at the source, it's cute clever trickery, but what if your string actually contains a `"\1"`?).

So I rolled my own. Here's what you get:

```
"oruh43451rohcs56oweuex59869rsr".unjoin(/\d+/)
# => ["oruh", "43451", "rohcs", "56", "oweuex", "59869", "rsr"]
```

And here's the implementation:

```
class Object
  def unfold(&f)
    (m, n = f[self]).nil? ? [] : n.unfold(&f).unshift(m)
  end
end

class String
  def unjoin(rx)
    unfold do |s|
      next if s.empty?
      ix = s =~ rx
      case
      when ix.nil?; [s , ""]
      when ix == 0; [$&, $']
      when ix >  0; [$`, $& + $']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(verbosier version at the bottom)

And here are some examples of corner cases being handled:

```
"".unjoin(/\d+/)     # => []
"w".unjoin(/\d+/)    # => ["w"]
"1".unjoin(/\d+/)    # => ["1"]
"w1".unjoin(/\d+/)   # => ["w", "1"]
"1w".unjoin(/\d+/)   # => ["1", "w"]
"1w1".unjoin(/\d+/)  # => ["1", "w", "1"]
"w1w".unjoin(/\d+/)  # => ["w", "1", "w"]
```

---

### And that's it, but here's more…

Or, if you don't like mucking with the built-in classes… well, you could use Refinements… but if you really don't like it, here it is as functions:

```
def unfold(x, &f)
  (m, n = f[x]).nil? ? [] : unfold(n, &f).unshift(m)
end

def unjoin(s, rx)
  unfold(s) do |s|
    next if s.empty?
    ix = s =~ rx
    case
    when ix.nil?; [s , ""]
    when ix == 0; [$&, $']
    when ix >  0; [$`, $& + $']
    end
  end
end
```

It also occurs to me that it may not always be clear which are the separators and which are the separated bits, so here's a little addition that lets you query a string with `#joint?` to know what role it played before the split:

```
class String

  def joint?
    false
  end

  class Joint < String
    def joint?
      true
    end
  end

  def unjoin(rx)
    unfold do |s|
      next if s.empty?
      ix = s =~ rx
      case
      when ix.nil?; [s, ""]
      when ix == 0; [Joint.new($&), $']
      when ix >  0; [$`, $& + $']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and here it is in use:

```
"oruh43451rohcs56oweuex59869rsr".unjoin(/\d+/)\
  .map { |s| s.joint? ? "(#{s})" : s }.join(" ")
# => "oruh (43451) rohcs (56) oweuex (59869) rsr"
```

You can now easily reimplement `split` and `scan`:

```
class String

  def split2(rx)
    unjoin(rx).reject(&:joint?)
  end

  def scan2(rx)
    unjoin(rx).select(&:joint?)
  end

end

"oruh43451rohcs56oweuex59869rsr".split2(/\d+/)
# => ["oruh", "rohcs", "oweuex", "rsr"]

"oruh43451rohcs56oweuex59869rsr".scan2(/\d+/)
# => ["43451", "56", "59869"]
```

### And if you hate match globals and general brevity…

```
class Object
  def unfold(&map_and_next)
    result = map_and_next.call(self)
    return [] if result.nil?
    mapped_value, next_value = result
    [mapped_value] + next_value.unfold(&map_and_next)
  end
end

class String
  def unjoin(regex)
    unfold do |tail_string|
      next if tail_string.empty?
      match = tail_string.match(regex)
      index = match.begin(0)
      case
      when index.nil?; [tail_string, ""]
      when index == 0; [match.to_s, match.post_match]
      when index >  0; [match.pre_match, match.to_s + match.post_match]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well… I guess this is still useful if you *don't* want the captures.